# React-Native FlatList scroll direction

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement infinite scroll on a FlatList, without loading tons of items in memory, we want to load lets say 100 items. And then depending on scroll we want to load more. So plan is, when user is scrolling up and 10 items remaining (I mean `onEndReachedThreshold` to 10) we would like to load next 50 items. After loading those 50 items, we would like to remove older 50 items from the data array, and push the new ones. And vice versa when scrolling down.

For scalability issue we don't want to load too many items in memory. But the problem is, on FlatList I couldn't find the scroll direction. I mean we should load next 50? Or previous 50?

Any suggestion how can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's how `onEndReachedThreshold` works. Also, if you read the docs here (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#onendreached), you need to specify a decimal for `onEndReachedThreshold`. So if you specify 0.5 then the list will load the next batch of data once the user has scrolled to the halfway mark of the list.

Comment: How many items do you have in particular? Because FlatList will handle this as only the visible items will be rendered and not all at once.

Comment: @Harrison , The documentation doesn't say anything about when you scroll down or down. The threshold value just invokes when scrolling up. I tried it, scroll at the bottom, and then try to scroll to the top, and you will see that its not calling when you reached the top end.

Comment: @moritzw , There is no specific amount of items. There can be 10, or 100 or half a millions.

Comment: @JahidShohel hey sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately this is a universal problem with all of us. Having the convenience of using javascript to write an app comes with the downsides of not being able to have as much performance as writing it in native code. That being said, the `<FlatList>` component is becoming more and more mature. I just found an article that implements redux to be more performant that might help (https://www.codementor.io/lsiden/getting-a-react-native-flatlist-to-be-performant-ik47nkj5q). In addition, there are other work-arounds, such as ui changes. Best of luck.